# String of hex characters to actual hex characters

Tags: ruby

I might be going about this the wrong way, and this might end up being a duplicate of something else.

I have a string that I need to convert into binary/hex.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
2.0.0p247 :050 > "test".unpack("H*").first
"74657374"
```

the `74657374` is the string of hex characters that I need, but I need them in actual hex, not a string.

How do I get this into `\x74\x65\x73\x74`?

I've tried `pack`ing the pairs of hex character, but they end up back in string form.  My goal is to parse a bunch of strings into hex and then write them out to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do nothing at all. `"\x74\x65\x73\x74"` is just another representation of `"test"`. Try in IRB:

```
"\x74\x65\x73\x74" == "test"
#=> true
```

Also consider:

```
$ ruby -e "File.open('test.txt', 'w'){|f| f.write 'test'}"
$ hexdump test.txt
0000000 74 65 73 74
0000004
```